# How can I create an image dynamically on AppEngine

Tags: java, image, google-app-engine

I have an application hosted in Java on AppEngine and I would like to add a feature where users can get a graphical summary of their data. BufferedImage is listed as not supported on AppEngine. The display process will be simple--a series of small squares in one of two colors.

Regards,

Kent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't find a better solution, you could delegate the graph generation to [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/types.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a format that fits nicely into a graph. Perhaps I need to rethink the format in that case... As far as I can tell there isn't a lightweight image library from Java apart from the code that ships in the JRE and I don't want to write a little right now.

Comment: I did change the format to fit a graph. Then I had to use AppEngine's URLFetch to get the image from Google Charts and stream it back to the requester. And it mostly works! Here is the little piece of flair showing the number of tests run through JUnit Max per hour for the last ten hours: http://junitmax.appspot.com/flair

Comment: Why fetch it using URLFetch? The whole idea of Google Charts is that you can embed a charts URL directly in the page and have it show the user a chart - there's no need for the indirection via your app.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs on the [image service](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview.html) in App Engine. You can probably do what you want with the composition functionality.